# w2ui grid how to get sortData to sort on initialize

Tags: w2ui

I have copied the example on the `grid sortData` http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.sortData and added `sortable:true` to `lname`, but the grid does not sort until I click the header.  What am I doing wrong.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snwaw16v/

```
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({
    name    : 'grid',
    columns: [                
        { field: 'recid', caption: 'ID', size: '50px' },
        { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%', sortable: true },
        { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '40%' },
        { field: 'sdate', caption: 'End Date', size: '120px' }
    ],
    records: [
        { recid: 1, fname: 'John', lname: 'doe', email: 'vitali@gmail.com', sdate: '1/3/2012' },
        { recid: 2, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '2/4/2012' },
        { recid: 3, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/23/2012' },
        { recid: 4, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '5/3/2012' },
        { recid: 5, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 6, fname: 'Francis', lname: 'Gatos', email: 'vitali@gmail.com', sdate: '2/5/2012' }
    ],
    sortData: [
        { field: 'lname', direction: 'asc' }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: External links are not helpful for future folks.  Please paste your code in here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the grid on render using *sort* method with the *onRender* event.

You may add this to your grid object :

```
onRender: function(event){
    this.sort('lname', 'asc');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gridData = $('#grid').w2grid({ 

// Keep your existed code

});

// Add this line code

gridData.localSort();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  While your proposed code might solve the OP's problem, the above answer lacks explanation or context.  Consider editing your answer to provide an explanation about why or how your solution resolves the question at hand.  See the community guidelines on how to answer questions- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer